# Excel-Possibility of conditional based grouping in Pivot tables

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, pivot-table, grouping

I am new to Pivot tables and would like to know the possibility of grouping in Pivot table based on conditions. For example, in the Sample data image, for Product P1, I grouped 'France and UK' into 'Europe' group and the group is reflecting under P2 product as well. My requirement is I would like to see 'Europe' under P1 but it should remain 'UK' under Product P2, without any grouping. Is it possible to group based on Product as per the example, please help.

***Sample data***
[image]

Comment: *My requirement is I would like to see 'Europe' under P1 but it should remain 'UK' under Product P1* i guess you mean *it should remain UK under PRoduct P2*. And as far as I know, it's not possible, Once you've created a group, it groups everything in all cases, not just sometimes. Consider maybe using a helper column in your data, and add this extra column to your Pivot Table

Comment: agree with @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns.  The only way it seems is through an additional helper column